# Oraclе - основные термины и понятия

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Я в начале пути по изучению оракла и мне уже сложно различать и понимать некоторые основные понятия. Может кто-то доходчиво и популярно обьяснить такие понятия:

- инстанция (instance)
- сид (SID)
- пользователь (user)
- схема (schema)

И как все эти понятия связаны и взаимодействуют в оракл?

Я понимаю что instance используется для работы с конкретной БД и представляет собой процессы оракла и SGA.  SID служит идентификатором в частности для выделения SGA для пользователя.

Одним instance может пользоваться один пользователь или несколько? Сколько может быть схем в инстансе? Пользователь имеет доступ к БД через инстанс и может использоват разные схемы или 1 пользователь = 1 схема? Разные инстансы могут работать с одной и тойже БД? Один инстанс может относится к разным БД?

Comment: А какие у вас общие познания в области баз данных, не зависимо от оракла?

Comment: Вопрос слишком широко поставлен. Почитайте Oracle Database Concepts что ли...

Comment: Последняя правка не пролила свет на вопрос: а что осталось не понятным? Так как вопрос в правке по причине "слишком общий", предлагаю убрать пока: юзер и схема, и добавить  database.

Comment: В instance нет ни схем, ни пользователей. SID это уникальный идентификатор instance и служит для выделения SGA для него, а не для пользователей.